# 403 from "Dynamically configured mass virtual hosting"

Tags: apache-2.2

I've looked at Apaches documented [Dynamically configured mass virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html), from which I've taken

```
UseCanonicalName Off
LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
CustomLog /tmp/access_log vcommon
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/localhost/htdocs/%0/web
VirtualScriptAlias /var/www/localhost/htdocs/%0/web
```

My expectation is that for my local development server, this will save me from needing to set up a new vhost file for every new domain I start with.

1. To make sure Apache is picking up the file, I add some junk, "dlkmvasp" to the top, check that I get a syntax error, remove junk, and restart the server again.
2. I add a few domains to /etc/hosts, and try to access loc.example.com.
3. "tail -f /tmp/access_log" now yields "loc.example.com 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2012:11:37:03 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 265"

How do I debug this? I can post all the vhost config is it's helpful, I just didn't wanna start of with a wall of text if it is not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're getting a `403` rather than a `404` it looks like it's being found; do you just need something like:

```
<Directory /var/www/localhost/htdocs>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

?

Answer (score 2):

In your example `loc.example.com` will have a `DocumentRoot` of `/var/www/localhost/htdocs/loc.example.com/web`.

Check that the path `/var/www/localhost/htdocs/loc.example.com/web` and files in the `web` directory have suitable permissions to allow Apache to access them. For the directories apache will need `r-x` permissions and for the files it will need `r--`